# Массив не существует в текущем контексте

Tags: c#

только начал изучать C# и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Пытаюсь объединить два массива в один, но к сожалению, в методе MethodUnion он их не видит.
Почитал про - "область видимости", но чего-то до конца, так видимо и не понял.

```
internal class Program
{

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Input number");
        MethodNumbers();
        Console.WriteLine("____");
        Console.WriteLine("____");
        ContinuationCheck();
        Console.WriteLine("____");
        Console.WriteLine("Input Name");
        MethodName();
        Console.WriteLine("____");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public async static void MethodNumbers()
    {
        long[] arrayNumber = new long[3];
        string patch = "D:/text.txt";
        char plas = '+';
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            number = number.Trim(plas);
            long.TryParse(number, out long truNumber);
            if (number.Length==11)
            {
                arrayNumber[i] = truNumber;
                Console.WriteLine(arrayNumber[i]);
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(patch, true))
                {
                    await writer.WriteAsync(number);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No right number");
                break;
            }
           
        }
    }
    public static void ContinuationCheck()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue?");
        string yes = Console.ReadLine();
        if (yes=="yes")
        {
            MethodNumbers();
        }
        else if (yes=="no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NT!");
           
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
            ContinuationCheck();
        }
        
    }
    public static void MethodName()
    {
        
        string[] arrayName = new string[3];
       // this.arrayName=arrayName;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.Length; i++)
        {
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            arrayName[i] = name;
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
    public static void MethodUnion()
    {
        
       var arrayUnion=new object[3];
        
       for (int i = 0; i < arrayName.Length; i++)
        {
            var arrayUnion = arrayNumber.Take(i).Concat(arrayName.Take(i));
        }
    }

}
```

//исправление ошибок

```
введите сюда код
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        User user = new User(number, name);
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(user.Number);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
public class User
{
    public string number;
    public string name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return name;
        } 
    }
    public string Number
    {
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
    public User() { }
    public User(string Name, string number)
    {
        number = Number;
        number = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Number);  
    }
}
```

Что-то трудновато идут свойства и конструкторы

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        User user = new User();
        User userr = new User(user.Name, user.Number);
        Console.WriteLine("_______________");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
public class User
{
    public string number;
    public string name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get 
        {
            return name;
        } 
    }
    public string Number
    {
       
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
    }
    public User() { }
    public User(string Name, string Number)
    {
        name = Name;
        number = Number;
        Console.WriteLine("Name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Number");
        number = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(name);
        Console.WriteLine(number);
        Console.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Тут всю систему менять нужно." Почитайте ещё про статические методы и поля класса. Посмотрите примеры. Тут у вас не только с этим проблемы на самом деле.

Comment: Дело в том, что вы пытаетесь отредактировать массив из другого контекста. Представьте есть 2 человека. 1 вы отправили создавать массив, а 2 занимается другими делами. И вот, 2 человек приходит к 1 и пытается изменить его массив, но 1 человек ещё не закончил выполнение этой задачи, поэтому и возникает исключение. Варианты решения - ждать ответ от async метода (.Result()) или пересмотреть подход к задаче (конечно, есть ещё и другие варианты). Возможно, поставленную перед вами задачу, можно решить иным путём. Отредактируйте этот вопрос и напишите ниже, какую задачу вы хотите выполнить

Comment: Смысл программы - кто-то вводит номер телефона, затем имя и это все записывается в новый массив, дальше по идеи это все будет записываться в txt файл.
Я думал, что так как они в одном классе  то проблем с видимость не будет.
PS задачка взята из головы, просто тренируюсь писать код.

Comment: @Ivan Написал краткое содержание, как можно решить вашу задачу. Прочитайте всю документацию, которую я приложил к ответу. В случае возникновения вопросов, оставляйте их под моим ответом

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понять суть ошибки, надо разобраться с тем, а что же такое "контекст". В C# это по сути текущий блок кода, выделенный фигурнми скобками `{ }`. При этом контексты не видят содержимое друг друга, исключение составляет контекст, вложенный в другой контекст, он видит содержимое старшего контекста.

Вот пример

```
{
   контекст 1
   {
       контекст 2
   }
}
{
    контекст 3
}
```

К этом примере только `контекст 2` видит содержимое `контекста 1`, больше никаких взаимоотношений между контекстами нет, `контекст 3` полностью изолирован.

Для обмена данными между контекстами есть множество способов:

- Публичные статические члены в публичном контексте
- Ссылка на экземпляр объекта
- Аргументы и возвращаемые значения методов

Контексты - неотъемлемая часть языка, они позволяют разделить вам код на блоки, использовать переменные с одинаковыми именами в разных контекстах и т.д.

---

К примеру, есть у вас метод `Main` с какой-то переменной. И есть второй метод, которому надо этой переменной воспользоваться.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 42;
    Print();
}

static void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // здесь ошибка, что "x не существует в данном контексте"
}
```

Есть 2 основных решения:

1. Вынести `x` в старший контекст, то есть сделать полем класса

```
static int x;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    x = 42;
    Print();
}

static void Print()
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // работает
}
```

2. Передать данные через аргумент вызываемого метода

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 42;
    Print(x);
}

static void Print(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x); // и это тоже работает
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарий автора: "Смысл программы - кто-то вводит номер телефона, затем имя и это все записывается в новый массив, дальше по идеи это все будет записываться в txt файл. Я думал, что так как они в одном классе то проблем с видимость не будет. PS задачка взята из головы, просто тренируюсь писать код."

Давайте тогда проанализируем поставленную задачу: нам нужно получить от пользователя данные и как-то их сохранить.

Первое, что нужно сделать, создать класс User или Person, в котором нужно описать необходимые свойства (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php). Очевидные свойства:

```
string PhoneNumber { get; }
string Name { get; }
```

Далее, в этом классе создать конструктор (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.35.php). Например,

```
public Person (string PhoneNumber, string Name) { ... (код напишите внутри сами) }
```

Так же, если хотите запариться, можете добавить валидацию номера телефона (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970244/how-to-validate-a-country-specific-phone-number)

Очевидно, что эти данные нужно где-то хранить. Но почему именно массив? Вы можете чётко сказать, сколько конкретно пользователей будет пытаться вводить свои данные? Думаю, тут лучше подойдёт List (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/4.5.php). Таким образом, вам нужно будет создать List, в который с помощью метода Add() вы будете добавлять пользователей.

Итак, теперь мы сохранили наших пользователей в программе, но в задаче вы указали, что нам их нужно сохранить в текстовый файл. Конечно, я бы тут поспорил с вами, что лучше хранить такое в базе данных, но раз уж текстовый файл, то ладно.

Наиболее простой способ - сериализовать данные в JSON и вставить полученную строку в текстовый файл (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.4.php).

Таким образом, мы сохраним данные в нашем файле. Для считывания этих данных нужно прочитать ту JSON строку из файла и десериализовать её (выше была ссылка на статью об этом)

Помните, что не стоит писать абсолютно всё в статике. Это крайне плохая реализация. Постарайтесь воспользоваться передачей переменных с помощью параметров в методы (https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.9.php) и там уже их использовать.

Так же, постарайтесь забыть о многопоточности и асинхронности. Не думаю, что действительно это может потребоваться. В данной задаче нет "тяжёлых процессов", которые-бы замедляли программу настолько сильно.

UPD:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; private set; } //Свойства пишутся с БОЛЬШОЙ буквы

    public string Number { get; private set; }

    public User(string name, string number)
    {
        Name = name;
        Number = number;
        // В конструкторе НЕ ДОЛЖНО быть сложной логики. Он должен максимально быстро отрабатывать. Все ваши Console.WriteLine и прочее - то, что здесь совершенно не должно быть
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        string number = Console.ReadLine();
        var user = new User(name, number);
        Console.WriteLine(user.Name);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !

Comment: Я не как не могу понять, почему код не хочет доходить до конструктора.
Получается, что я вызываю новый экземпляр класса User и он мне возвращает number. без изменений.
Но если я вызываю новый экземпляр класса с конструктором, то мне туда надо ввести значения - name и number, а их не существует в данном контексте 
User user = new User(number, name)
Ошибка Имя "number" не существует в текущем контексте. Но я же их создал публичными в классе User.  
public string number;
public string name;

Comment: Вроде понял как использовать конструктор, если не сложно посмотрите правильно ли.
Просто мне, кажется, что вот эти объявление нового экземпляра  - даже выглядят не очень

Comment: @Ivan Что значит "код не хочет доходить до конструктора"? Если вы создали экземпляр класса в одном контексте, то в другой её нужно передать так, как описано в ответе aepot. Далее, вы говорите, что "Вызываете новый экземпляр класса User". Это не корректно. Экземпляр класса вы СОЗДАЁТЕ, передав в него какие-то параметры. Пример: "var user = new User(number, name);". Если number не существует в текущем контексте, то соответственно компилятор на это и ругается. Передайте в нужный контекст эту переменную и проблема решена. Можете отредактировать свой вопрос и добавить код, в котором возникает....

Comment: ...возникает ошибка. Для этого нажмите "Править", отступите несколько строк, напишите UPD и вставьте свой код. "создал публичными в классе User. public string number; public string name" - Вы создали СВОЙСТВА внутри класса User. Вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр класса. не путайте эти вещи. Советую к просмотру - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z9vkieAyfM

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ. То, как написали вы в своём вопросе - не совсем правильный код. Создалось чувство, что вы даже не прочитали статьи, которые я указывал. Иначе, подобных вопросов-бы не возникало